# Bibliographical references to Hilbert's theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, submanifold

I want to do a thorough investigation of Hilbert's Theorem and them Efimov's Theorem:

(Hilbert's Theorem) A complete surface $S$ with constant negative curvature can't be isometrically immersed in $R^3$.

(Efimov's Theorem) A complete surface with Gauss curvature $K\leq k_0<0$ can't be isometrically immersed in $R^3$.

and I would like to know if anyone knows good bibliographical references on it apart from the book by Do Carmo. I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some papers/links on imbedding surfaces of negative curvature:

- Mathoverflow post: [Surfaces in $\mathbb R^3$ with negative curvature bounded away from zero](https://mathoverflow.net/q/111101/90655)
- *Efimov, N. V.*, [Impossibility of isometric immersion into three-dimensional Euclidean space of certain manifolds with negative Gaussian curvature](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/getFT.phtml?jrnid=dan&paperid=26973&what=fullt&option_lang=rus), Sov. Math., Dokl. 3 (1962), 1293-1297 (1963); translation from Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR 146, 296-299 (1962). [ZBL0137.40702](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0137.40702).
- *Efimov, N. V.*, [Impossibility of a complete regular surface in Euclidean 3-space whose Gaussian curvature has a negative upper bound](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/getFT.phtml?jrnid=dan&paperid=28206&what=fullt&option_lang=eng), Sov. Math., Dokl. 4, 843-846 (1963); translation from Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR 150, 1206-1209 (1963). [ZBL0135.40001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0135.40001).
- *Han, Qing; Hong, Jia-Xing*, Isometric embedding of Riemannian manifolds in Euclidean spaces, Mathematical Surveys and Monographs 130. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS) (ISBN 0-8218-4071-1/hbk). xiv, 260 p. (2006). [ZBL1113.53002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1113.53002).
- *Klotz Milnor, Tilla*, [**Efimov’s theorem about complete immersed surfaces of negative curvature**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(72)90007-2), Adv. Math. 8, 474-543 (1972). [ZBL0236.53055](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0236.53055).
- *J J Stoker,* ON THE EMBEDDING OF SURFACES OF NEGATIVE CURVATURE IN 3-DIMENSIONAL EUCLIDEAN SPACE
- *Shikin, E. V.*, [**Equations of isometric imbeddings in three-dimensional Euclidean space of two-dimensional manifolds of negative curvature**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01138942), Math. Notes 31, 305-312 (1982). [ZBL0499.53004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0499.53004).
- *Poznyak, É.G., Shikin, E.V.* [Surfaces of negative curvature](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01085151). J Math Sci 5, 865–887 (1976).