# Where is it possible to have an isometric immersion of $\mathbb{H}^2$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, isometry

I'm researching the **Hilbert's Theorem**.- *There is no isometric immersion of the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb{H}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.* But on the way I have come across several results, such as:

**Efimov's theorem**.- *There is no isometric immersion of a complete surface with Gaussian curvature bounded superiorly by a negative constant, at $\mathbb{R}^3$.*

Then the question arose, where is it possible to have an isometric immersion of $\mathbb{H}^2$? I read that there is an isometric immersion in $\mathbb{R}^5$, but I only got this result,

**Blanusa's theorem**.- *There is an isometric embedding proper to the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb{H}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^6$.*

From Efimov's theorem I have managed to find references to read, but from Blanusa's Theorem or other similar ones I have not obtained much information. If someone knows the topics and could give me some references or perhaps other theorems that can enrich my research, I would appreciate it very much.

> Some documents i have found:
>
> - D. Brander - Isometric Embeddings between Space Forms
> - T. Milnor - Efimov's theorem about complete immersed surface of negative curvature
> - Do Carmo - Differential geometry
> - And others [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4104556/bibliographical-references-to-hilberts-theorem)

Comment: Have you seen already [this thesis](http://davidbrander.org/penn.pdf)?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned it on the list.

Answer (score 3):

It is proven by Rozendorn that ${\mathbb H}^2$ admits an isometric immersion in ${\mathbb E}^5$. See Prop. 2.2.5 in

*Han, Qing; Hong, Jia-Xing*, Isometric embedding of Riemannian manifolds in Euclidean spaces, Mathematical Surveys and Monographs 130. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS) (ISBN 0-8218-4071-1/hbk). xiv, 260 p. (2006). [ZBL1113.53002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1113.53002).

This book will contain proofs of most of the known results, assuming that your target space is Euclidean. For non-Euclidean targets, you have to ask a more focused question.